# Android - Check the package of an app

Tags: android, package

Suppose I got an apk file, how can I check the package of it?
Should I use the tools like **apktool** to fulfill this action?

The package mean "com.example.helloworld"

Thanks

Comment: Yes, using apktool would be best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. apktool is a great tool for this. To use apktool:

```
apktool d application.apk application-apk
```

After that, inspect `application-apk/AndroidManifest.xml` file and look at the `<manifest>` root element at the top.

Answer (score 0):

You have different tools:

Apktool

Android Multitool

Apk Viewer

ApkShellext